# Why are .catch callbacks executed at the end of the microtask queue?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, chaining

I have the following code in an HTML file:

```js
const fooBar = function(resolve, reject) {
 let flag = (Math.round(Math.random() * 10) % 2);
 if(flag)
  resolve({ "value": "foo", "rand": Math.random() });
 else
  reject({ "value": "bar", "rand": Math.random() });
};
const fooBarSuccess1 = function(value) {
 console.log("Success 1:" + JSON.stringify(value));
};
const fooBarFailure1 = function(value) {
 console.log("Failure 1:" + JSON.stringify(value));
};
const fooBarSuccess2 = function(value) {
 console.log("Success 2:" + JSON.stringify(value));
};
const fooBarFailure2 = function(value) {
 console.log("Failure 2:" + JSON.stringify(value));
};
new Promise(fooBar).then(fooBarSuccess1).catch(fooBarFailure1);
new Promise(fooBar).then(fooBarSuccess2, fooBarFailure2);
console.log("Before setting MicroTask.");
setTimeout(() => console.log("This Timeout was set before the MicroTask!"));
queueMicrotask(() => console.log("From MicroTask!"));
console.log("After setting MicroTask.");
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1q5ya6wb/)

When the Promise gets rejected, `fooBarFailure1` is executed at the end of the microtask queue, so you might get the below output:

```
Before setting MicroTask.
After setting MicroTask.
Success 2:{"value":"foo","rand":0.3675094508130746}
From MicroTask!
Failure 1:{"value":"bar","rand":0.6828171208953322}
This Timeout was set before the MicroTask!
```

However, shouldn't it be invoked before the code inside `queueMicrotask` is executed? And I don't see any such issues with `fooBarFailure2`. It gets executed in the expected order. The result is the same in Firefox 71 and Google Chrome 78. Can anybody explain what's happening here?

Comment: Side note: If you want a flag with a 50/50 split between `true` and `false`, you can do it a bit more simply than in the above if you like: `let flag = Math.random() < 0.5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `fooBarFailure1` is further away from the root promise (the one from `new Promise`) than `fooBarFailure2` is. `fooBarFailure1` isn't connected to the root promise, it's connected to the one created by `.then(fooBarSuccess1)`:

```
new Promise(fooBar).then(fooBarSuccess1).catch(fooBarFailure1);
```

In contrast, `fooBarSuccess2` and `fooBarFailure2` are **both** attached to the root promise:

```
new Promise(fooBar).then(fooBarSuccess2, fooBarFailure2);
```

There's an internal rejection handler in the chain before `fooBarFailure1`, but the `fooBarFailure2` is hooked directly. That's what causes the extra async "tick".

Let's look at just the failure example, because it simplifies things:

```js
const success = function(value) {
    console.log("This never happens");
};
const fooBarFailure1 = function(value) {
    console.log("Failure 1");
};
const fooBarFailure2 = function(value) {
    console.log("Failure 2");
};
Promise.reject().then(success).catch(fooBarFailure1);
Promise.reject().then(success, fooBarFailure2);
console.log("Before setting MicroTask.");
setTimeout(() => console.log("This Timeout was set before the MicroTask!"));
queueMicrotask(() => console.log("From MicroTask!"));
console.log("After setting MicroTask.");
```

The output of that is:

```
Before setting MicroTask.
After setting MicroTask.
Failure 2
From MicroTask!
Failure 1
This Timeout was set before the MicroTask!
```

Here's why:

- `Promise.reject()` returns a rejected promise in both cases.
- In `Promise.reject().then(success).catch(fooBarFailure1);`

  - `.then(success)` creates a new promise and hooks up fulfillment and rejection handlers; the rejection handler is internal and just passes on the rejection reason, since no rejection handler was supplied.
  - `.catch(fooBarFailure1)` hooks up a rejection handler on the promise from `then`.
- Since the promise is rejected, it uses a microtask to call the rejection handler attached to it.
- In `Promise.reject().then(success, fooBarFailure2);`:

  - `then` hooks up both the fulfillment handler (`success`) and the rejection handler (`fooBarFailure2`) to the promise from `Promise.reject()`
- Since the promise is rejected, it uses a microtask to call the rejection handler attached to it.
- `"Before setting MicroTask."` is logged.
- The `setTimeout` queues its task
- The `queueMicrotask` queues its microtask
- `"After setting MicroTask."` is logged.
- The task scheduling all this completes, so microtask processing starts

  - The first microtask is dealing with the rejection from `Promise.reject().then(success).catch(fooBarFailure1);`: That rejects the promise created by `then`, queuing a microtask to call the rejection handler on the promise `then` returned.
  - The second microtask is dealing with the rejection from `Promise.reject().then(success, fooBarFailure2);`: That rejects the promise, calling `fooBarFailure2`.

    - `"Failure 2"` is logged.
  - The third microtask is the one from `queueMicrotask`, which runs.

    - `"From MicroTask!"` is logged.
  - The microtask call to `fooBarFailure1`, scheduled above, runs.

    - `"Failure 1"` is logged.
- The next task runs, calling the timer callback

  - `"This Timeout was set before the MicroTask!"` is logged.